# SQL Server Management Studio: How to edit MD5 value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, hash, md5, sql-server-2008-express

I have table `[user]`, created in SQL Server Management Studio, with this structure:

```
id int PRIMARY NOT NULL  
login varchar(255) NOT NULL  
password varchar(32) NOT NULL
```

Now, I want to insert first user into database. Right click to table `[user]`, choose `Edit top 200 rows` and type new user values into the grid:

```
id    | login    | password
1     | admin    | MD5('admin')
```

But after save, inserted password is `MD5('admin')`, but I expect the `21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3` hash.

How can I do that in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?

Thanks

P.S. I am using SQL Server 2008 Express 10.50.1600.1 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 10.50.1600.1.

Comment: `MD5` isn't a built in function. There's `HASHBYTES`, but it returns `varbinary`, not `varchar`, and you can't edit `varbinary` through the edit grid.

Answer (score 3):

1. hash values are byte arrays, not character strings. Use VARBINARY column type.
2. Do not insert MD5 of unsalted passwords. It [takes 2.96 seconds to reverse crack *online* the hash to the password](http://www.tmto.org/pages/passwordtools/hashcracker/). Use a properly salted password and write the salt in the table.
3. `Right click to table [user], choose Edit top 200 rows and type new user values into the grid`. Well, what do you expect? The table edit is a feature to enter values, and if you enter the string `MD5('admin')` then the value in the table will be... `MD5('admin')`. It is not an interactive function evaluator (aside from MD5 not being a SQL Server function...)

Do not reinvent the wheel, specially do not reinvent a security wheel if you don't speak fluent crypto. Most frameworks have modules for membership management. Eg. [Introduction to Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run queries in grid tables, you have to run query to do update. To calculate MD5 you can use:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'admin'), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Edit Top 200 Rows` feature is for *interactive* data entry, where only values are accepted, not expressions that need to be evaluated before being stored.

If you want the actual value inserted to be the result of an expression, use a *query* window to insert the data. (I don't know if you used the `Edit` feature merely because you wanted to try that functionality or for some other reason, but if that was because you didn't know how to insert data using SQL, take a look at [this manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174335.aspx).)

Also, as [@Damien has correctly noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833934/sql-server-management-studio-how-to-edit-md5-value#comment22527245_15833934), there's no `MD5` function in Transact-SQL. There is one called [`HASHBYTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx), which can use various hashing algorithms, including MD5. But the result of this function is `varbinary`, not `varchar`. For MD5 specifically, it is `varbinary(16)`. To store the direct result of `HASHBYTES`, therefore, you'll need to change the type of the `password` column accordingly.

So, change the type of the column, then open a new query window and type in a *command* (or *statement*) to insert the data. The one that should do the job for you might look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO user (id, login, password)
VALUES (1, 'admin', HASHBYTES('MD5', 'admin'));
```

To be fair, you *may* omit changing the column type, in which case you'll need to replace the simple `HASHBYTES` call like above with one like in [@Garath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15834255/297408). Whether you really *need* to store the hashes as `varchar(32)` instead of `varbinary(16)` is an entirely different question, though.